# Unix: Unexpected behavior of grep command with regex search

Tags: unix, grep, logfile, log-files

I have a grep command that I run daily to find an entry in a huge logfile.

This command works fine in our Development environment. But in our Production environment, it outputs a response that is different from the entry in the logfile.

Here's the command:

```
logentry=$(grep -m1 -oP '.*(?<=Reset\s).*' $log)
```

Actual entry in log file:

```
******Reset  Counter:[Total:1849766] [Success:1849766]  [Insert:102]  [Update:1848861]  [Delete:803]  [Key:0]
```

Command output:

```
******Reset  Counter:[Total:1849766] 1  [Insert:102]  [Update:1848861]  [Delete:803]  [Key:0]
```

Expected output:

```
 ******Reset  Counter:[Total:1849766] [Success:1849766]  [Insert:102]  [Update:1848861]  [Delete:803]  [Key:0]
```

What could be the reason behind this inconsistent behavior of the grep command?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: i have added expected output to question. the success count field gets replaced by 1 most of the time

Comment: more importantly - how are you displaying the `logentry` to verify that it's correct? It's got the smell of a glob pattern finding a file called `1`

Comment: i use echo $logentry to print it. if that is the case then it should be true always.

Comment: That'd do it then - you're not quoting your variable so it's open to globbing, word-splitting, and filename expansion and so the net result will be dependent on files in your directory. Use `echo "$logentry"` instead and ALWAYS quote your shell variab;es unless you have a specific purpose in mind by not doing so and fully understand all of the implications.

Comment: if i use print along with quote then would it work?

Comment: What's the point of the fancy grep command, btw,, vs a simple `grep -m1 'Reset' file`?

Comment: when I use logentry variable within quotes it seems working. I will monitor it for few days then update question as resolved. "Ed Morton" I put partial regex in query in question, the purpose is positive look-behind.

Comment: You'll want to read [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: @RahulSharma positive look-behind isn't a purpose it's just what the script is doing, I was asking why you're doing it.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the "Reset", like `grep -m1 -oP '(?<=Reset\s).*' "${log}"` ? Then please correct your expected and wanted output. The current wanted output is the same as a simple grep.

Comment: thanks for suggestions, fix is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Ed Morton for comment. The fix is working fine.
 
Root cause:
The variable is not quoted so it's open to globbing, word-splitting, and filename expansion and so the net result will be dependent on files in your directory.

Solution: Use echo "$logentry" instead and ALWAYS quote your shell variabes unless you have a specific purpose in mind by not doing so and fully understand all of the implications.

[Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)